# "Answer" count is not updated on questions page

Tags: bug

Question Link: [How to check if object in nested array contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77843483/how-to-check-if-object-in-nested-array-contains-a-value)

There is an accepted answer for this question, however, the answer count still shows as 0 on the Questions page. See screenshot below:

[image]

Accepted answer on the question:
[image]

Please note: I'm not seeing this issue for any other question as of now.

Comment: Apparently this will fix itself in a day (Don't know why it happened in this case though): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95240/wrong-count-of-answers-in-question/95272#95272

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You posted your answer at 03:00, but our scheduled task that normalizes the answer count for all questions in the system also runs at 03:00. When you post answers so close to the normalization task running, there is a non-zero chance that the task will overwrite the new answer count from posting your answer with the prior answer count it had when it started running.

Fortunately, it'll already be fixed the next day when the normalization task runs again.